# Karma test for angular directive giving Error: $sce:insecurl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test for a directive called calendar week and I am getting the following angular error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=http:%2F%2Fhere.com%2Fviews%2Fdirectives%2FcalendarWeek.html

My spec has

```
describe('Tests for CalendarWeek Directive', function(){
  var el, scope, controller;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('MyApp');
    return inject(function($injector, $compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $sce) {
      el = angular.element("<div calendar-week></div>");
      $compile(el)($rootScope.$new());
      $rootScope.$digest();
      controller = el.controller("calendarWeek");
      $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://here.com/views/directives/calendarWeek.html")
      $httpBackend.whenGET("http://here.com/views/directives/calendarWeek.html").respond({ hello: 'World' });
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: why while testing the directive you test server request? the directive should only manipulate the DOM and this is what should be tested. resources that request data from server should be tested separately

Comment: If you follow the link in the error message you will see exactly what you are missing: Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked. Angular is blocking you from loading an insecure resource: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce):
By default, Angular only loads templates from the same domain and protocol as the application document. This is done by calling $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl on the template URL. To load templates from other domains and/or protocols, you may either whitelist them or wrap it into a trusted value.

You are trying to load a resource either from a different domain or a different protocol. I think you need to be wrapping your URL like this:

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET($sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://here.com/views/directives/calendarWeek.html")).respond({ hello: 'World' });
```

Or whitelist it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  
    'http://here.com/views/directives/calendarWeek.html'
  ]);

});
```